# how to setup virtual box guest additions (drivers) on systemd system (exherbo)

Tags: virtualbox, systemd

The trouble is when I run ./VBoxLinuxA... I'm getting:

**Unable to determine your Linux distribution**

so there is build in script :

```
check_system_type() {
    if [ ! "$ro_SYS_TYPE" = "" ]; then
        return 0
    elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ]; then
        ro_SYS_TYPE=debian
        ro_INIT_TYPE=sysv
    elif [ -f /etc/gentoo-release ]; then
        ro_SYS_TYPE=gentoo
        ro_INIT_TYPE=sysv
    elif [ -x /sbin/chkconfig ]; then
        ro_SYS_TYPE=redhat
        ro_INIT_TYPE=sysv
    elif [ -x /sbin/insserv ]; then
        ro_SYS_TYPE=suse
        ro_INIT_TYPE=sysv
    elif [ -f /etc/lfs-release -a -d /etc/rc.d/init.d ]; then
        ro_SYS_TYPE=lfs
        ro_INIT_TYPE=lfs
    elif [ -f /etc/pardus-release ]; then
        ro_SYS_TYPE=pardus
        ro_INIT_TYPE=pardus
    elif [ -f /etc/rc.d/rc.local ]; then
        ro_SYS_TYPE=unknown
        ro_INIT_TYPE=bsd
        ro_RC_LOCAL=/etc/rc.d/rc.local
    elif [ -f /etc/rc.local ]; then
        ro_SYS_TYPE=unknown
        ro_INIT_TYPE=bsd
        ro_RC_LOCAL=/etc/rc.local
    elif [ -d /etc/init.d ]; then
        ro_SYS_TYPE=unknown
        ro_INIT_TYPE=sysv
    else  # Perhaps we can determine what we need to know anyway though?
        echo 1>&2 "Unable to determine your Linux distribution"
        log "Unable to determine the Linux distribution"
        return 1
    fi
    return 0
}
```

And I'm confused what can I chose here. I'm using systemd I've tried to create various files but it still being wrong for me :(

How to install it for systemd? (fedora installs it somehow)

Add: seems like fedora had sysv-compatibility enabled in systemd and vbox don't support systemd. So I just need this hacky way to get drivers.

Comment: Can you add /exherbo tag?

Answer (score 1):

[Exherbo](http://exherbo.org), nice.  Well, the `[ -f /some/file ]` tests if the file exists and is a regular file.  Thus you should be able to fake any of these outcomes with `touch /the/file/indicating/the/distribution`.  (Respectively `mkdir` for the `[ -d /path/to/dir/ ]` tests.)

However, depending on how the script goes on, this might lead to trouble.

[The SUMMER package](http://git.exherbo.org/summer/packages/app-virtualization/virtualbox-ose/index.html) doesn't work for you?

Comment: so as I said I used to create this files, even you forget about -x which must be in 777 mode but they help me not, there is no option for pure systemd as far as I understand and the link you provided is not what I need, I need guest additions, not vbox itself.

Comment: The package offers an `additions` choice that should give you these, I suppose.

Comment: it's additions cd for vbox application, not for my guest system.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't know VBox.  (So it's not the `extensions` choice either, then?)  I can't tell from [the `exlib`](https://github.com/SuperHeron/exherbo-misc/blob/488cb6b8ffa41fb0b9eb42a856926f35275521c8/packages/app-virtualization/virtualbox-ose/virtualbox-ose.exlib) if they try to impersonate some other distribution...

Comment: Vbox-ose is just vbox... vbox additions is drivers which is build-in my vbox. I just need to install them somehow.

Comment: Well, I'm lost here, sorry.  If the file is there, the script shouldn't fail like that.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I'm creating a script which should install virtualbox-guest-additions based on gentoo ebuilds

https://github.com/rofrol/exherbo/blob/master/virtualbox-guest-additions.sh